# How to get range index value from given number

Tags: ios, swift

How to get the index of a value contained in a range?

```
var rangeValue = 30 ... 400
```

rangeValue[7]. // Seveth Index Value 36

Comment: Also your title and question are opposites. Do you want index from value or value from index?

Comment: @matt I need value from index.

Comment: @matt Thanks You its helps

Comment: I guess I need to make declaration in this formate     let rangeValue = Array(30...400). then access via rangeValue[indexValue].

Comment: It would’ve been better to explain why you think you have a need for this.

Comment: Just the better way to set  WeightValues -> KG / LB

Comment: I accept those Negative rating since my question not placed in proper way! :(

Comment: I do not see what the question has to do with kg / lb. please ask about the real problem you want to solve.

Comment: @kiran, converting range to array to just get one element it's a bad idea, you will just waste memory and processing power.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
 let rangeValue = Array(30 ... 400)
 rangeValue[7]
```

Answer (score 2):

Strictly spoken you can subscript a range but it's pretty cumbersome.

```
let rangeValue = 30...400
let index = rangeValue.index(rangeValue.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
let value = rangeValue[index]
```

By the way the value of the 7th index is 37.

---

Or syntactically simpler without subscription (inspired by Asperi's answer)

```
let rangeValue = 30...400
let value = rangeValue.lowerBound + 7
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it via small extension to the `ClosedRange` with subscript (tested in Playground, so anyone can copy-paste)

```
var rangeValue = 30 ... 400

extension ClosedRange where Bound == Int {
    public subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        return self.lowerBound + index
    }
}

rangeValue[7] // and this call is valid & gives 37
```

Comment: instead of `Bound == Int` it's better to generalise to all `Bound: AdditiveArithmetic`. Also, don't forget to check for `upperBound` "overflow".

Comment: This may accidentally give the right answer but you are not indexing, just adding two integers.

Comment: @matt, we consider closed sequence range of integers... please give an example when this will be wrong

Comment: If you’re going to argue that way, you should be arguing that the original question is pointless, as there is no need to index anything.